# SQL Query not displaying correctly

Tags: mysql, sql

I am running a query and the result is not showing correctly, unfortunately, I am not sure what is the problem. Would anyone be kind enough to provide some assistance please?

**Query;**

```
SELECT a."Article_id"
    ,a."Article_topic"
    ,c."Comment_content"
FROM PUBLIC."Articles" a
INNER JOIN PUBLIC."Comments" c ON a."Article_id" = c."Article_id"
WHERE c."Comment_id" = 2;
```

Result:

[image: Query Result]

Comment: How do you want it to show correctly?

Comment: It's adding too many ----, it should be displaying like this (this is for another query); https://i.imgur.com/aqUU6aJ.jpg

Comment: instead of the image can you share the results as text

Comment: Please add the expected result and the actual result as text to your question.

Comment: @makkie , Can you please try Left Join between the tables ,there might be possibilities that no match of the records ..

Comment: Note that `"` isn't a mysql construct

Comment: Also, that screen could do with a clean

Comment: Haha Strawberry, it's library PC, not my own!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that a field that you select is very big, that's why it's shown this way.

I'd bet on "Comment_content" having large values in it.

You can try something like :

```
SELECT a."Article_id"
    ,SUBSTRING(a."Article_topic", 0,50) as Article_topic_truncated
    ,SUBSTRING(c."Comment_content", 0,50) as Comment_content_truncated
FROM PUBLIC."Articles" a
INNER JOIN PUBLIC."Comments" c ON a."Article_id" = c."Article_id"
WHERE c."Comment_id" = 2;
```

Another way to fix that would be to show the results vertically.
You do so by ending the query with `\G` :

```
SELECT a."Article_id"
    ,a."Article_topic"
    ,c."Comment_content"
FROM PUBLIC."Articles" a
INNER JOIN PUBLIC."Comments" c ON a."Article_id" = c."Article_id"
WHERE c."Comment_id" = 2\G
```

Comment: This works, thank you! Does 0,50 - the number of chars? e.g. max 50

Answer (score 1):

E.g.:

```
SELECT a.Article_id
    , LEFT(a.Article_topic,15) article_topic
    , LEFT(c.Comment_content,15) comment_content
 FROM Articles a
 JOIN Comments c 
   ON a.Article_id = c.Article_id
WHERE c.Comment_id = 2;
```

Comment: that is just a copy of my answer without the explanation, and using LEFT instead of SUBSTRING... -_-'

Comment: Both were posted at the same time. And mine doesn't have those strange bits of punctuation. So, no, it ain't a copy. Weird

Answer (score -1):

I suggest making your query more readable and more human-friendly:

```
SELECT
    a.Article_id,
    a.Article_topic,
    c.Comment_content
FROM public.Articles a 
INNER JOIN public.Comments c ON a.Article_id = c.Article_id
WHERE c.Comment_id = 2
```

Your answer might be showing correctly - it could be that it just doesn't fit into your screen. Maybe try using GUI, like [PHPMyAdmin](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/)?

Answer (score -1):

I think you should try left join , please try below query

```
SELECT a."Article_id"
    ,a."Article_topic"
    ,c."Comment_content"
FROM PUBLIC."Articles" a
LEFT JOIN PUBLIC."Comments" c ON a."Article_id" = c."Article_id"
WHERE c."Comment_id" = 2;
```